# `less` starts `ed`

Tags: text-editors, less

I can't make `less` use my favorite editor. To my horror, it starts `ed` which I've never used and really am not going to.

```
> echo $EDITOR 
emacsclient
> less somefile
```

Pressing `v` starts `usr/bin/editor +7 somefile`. I've never seen `less` ignoring `$EDITOR`, so it may be an Ubuntu issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding "export EDITOR". The behaviour of unexported shell variables is really confusing, but I can reproduce this problem myself.

If that still doesn't work, "sudo update-alternatives –config editor" will let you configure /usr/bin/editor

Comment: My bad... I always use things like `export EDITOR=emacsclient; export VISUAL="$EDITOR"; 
export LESSEDIT="$EDITOR '%f'"` and this time I copied it from somebody else...

Answer (score 1):

`less` pays attention to three environment variables to determine what editor to invoke for the `v` command: `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR`, and `$LESSEDIT`.  `man less` and search for `LESSEDIT` for details.

Normally it probably makes sense to set `$EDITOR` to your favorite editor and leave `$VISUAL` and `$LESSEDIT` undefined.  (The distinction between `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` is probably not useful these days; it used to be a way to distinguish between a full-screen editor like `vi` and a line-oriented editor like `ed`.)

And as pjc50 says, be sure the `$EDITOR` variable is exported.